# Javascript anonymous functions in Firefox 7

Tags: javascript, firefox, anonymous-function

After updating to Firefox 7, I am getting the following error:

> function statement requires a name

This particular functions is defined as

```
fun = eval("function (item) { //Function body }");
```

If I rewrite it as:

```
fun = eval("function view(item) { //Function body }");
```

The error does not show up any more, but the program still does not work.

Ps.- I know that evaluating a string is not a good idea. This is a legacy application that I have to fix in which some functions are downloaded from a database as strings on demand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in brackets

```
eval("(function (item) { alert('hello'); })");
```

But that doesn't make sense as it does nothing. Maybe you want:

```
eval("(function () { alert('hello'); })()");
```

Or

```
eval("var func = function (item) { };");
```

Comment: The script actually evaluates the function and stores it in a dictionary. So your first solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for `eval` unless the function body is unknown when the code is loaded. Just get rid of `eval` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

A function declaration (is what you've got there) requires an identifier by spec.

```
function() {
}
```

just like that is not allowed by ES specification (even if some browsers might allow it anyway). Only function expression may be anonymous.

Comment: In certain cases, Firefox treats what might appear to be unnamed function declarations as function expressions, so it is a bit surprising that it complains in this case. Anyhow, wrapping it in a grouping operator makes it unequivocally a function expression so the name becomes optional.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, maybe try with:

```
fun = eval("return function (item) { //Function body }");
```

(I just added the return statement)

Answer (score 0):

if the function is defined as a string and you wish to use it without calling eval everytime, you could do this:

```
var myFunc = 'function(){alert("myFunc");}';    
var fun = eval('(function(){return '+myFunc+'})()');
fun();
```

Or just

```
var myFunc = 'function(){alert("myFunc");}';    
var fun = eval('('+myFunc+')');
fun();
```